# Cant Center my li within my ul In sidebar

Tags: html, css, html-lists, center

i'm pretty new to css and html and trying to make a site to work on improving and learning. I've been searching and cant figure out how to fix my menu in the sidebar, to me it looks like the li's in the ul are floating to the right for some reason, heres my code:

also Jsfiddle Link: 
https://jsfiddle.net/h2bpxcxe/

```
#side-bar #recents {
    width: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

#recents h3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 4px;
}

#recents ul {
    margin-top: -10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
}

#recents ul li {
    padding: 2% 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    background: grey;
```

Thanks if somone can help! :)

Comment: are you looking like this? https://jsfiddle.net/h2bpxcxe/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UL`-elements have a `padding-left` by default.
You need to reset this padding which will center your `li`-elements in your sidebar.

```
#recents ul {
    margin-top: -10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left:0px; //Adding this will center your LI's
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h2bpxcxe/4/)

a tip for when dealing with issues like this. Look at the element in your browsers developer tools. Padding and Margin will always be shown clearly there.

Answer (score 0):

I feel there is also an issue with the positioning of the sidebar's list/ul element.

If you apply:

```
#recents ul {
    position:absolute;
}
```

to your CSS, it will preclude the list element from overflowing the parent, which is the case with your current code. Here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/46t4f5zs/

Answer (score -1):

just do like this

```
<div id="recents">


            <ul><h3>Recent Posts</h3>
                <li><a href="#">Recent One</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Recent Two</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Recent Three</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Recent Four</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: that will align Recent Post and li's at center to each other

Comment: If you do this then the UL wont be centered relative to the rest of the content in the sidebar. The issue is the default padding of the UL.